# Could not set string value to setter

Tags: java

MyClass has a setter but when I assign a value to it I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MyClass.setValue(Ljava/lang/String;)
```

MyClassIfc.java

```
public interface MyClassIfc extends EYSDomainIfc
{     
      public abstract String getValue();

      public abstract void setValue(String paramString);

}
```

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass implements MyClassIfc
{
  protected String value = null;

  public String getValue() 
  {
      return this.value;
  }

  public void setValue(String paramString)
  {
      this.value= paramString;
  } 

}
```

Invoking sipnet:

```
MyClassIfc myClass = ((MyDomainObjectFactoryIfc)MyDomain.getFactory()).getMyInstance();
value = MyUtilities.getValue(utility, data, logger, serviceName);
myClass.setValue(value);
```

Comment: Please show your class. Perhaps the setter is not be public?

Comment: `Ljava/lang/String` is the type string for `String[]`, not `String`. Knowing how  you're calling this method would help significantly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I prepare to show MyClass but I see MyClass has not implemented the getter and setter(setValue and getValue) from MyClassIfc(an interface) yet. This may be the cause.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I added getter and setter to MyClass but still the same error. I showed my classes, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you're trying to run a different version of that class from the one that you used at compile time.  Clean out your build directories and recompile everything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code you did write in your class? Whenever you get NoSuchMethod the first thing you'd like to look at is the method signature.

For example:

- Modifiers—such as public, private, etc: Make sure you get access modifier right, if you are calling the method creating an instance of the class (an object) and that method is private you won't be able to access it.
- The method name: take a closer look to the method name and make sure you are typing it correctly. If you are using an IDE just let the autocomplete help you to avoid errors.
- The parameter list their data types: Make sure the data-type of the variable/object you are passing to the method matches the datatype that the method has declared (what the method is expecting).

In your case, I would go for the parameter list first.

If you want to read more about method definition you can go to the java reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I showed and checked my code and it passed your suggestions. Pls, help.